# How to use SQL query result as shiny drop down input?

Tags: sql, r, shiny

I am creating a simple shiny app that asks a user to choose a year and then draws a histogram of the sum of sales from that year.

I would like for shiny to fetch the years from an sql query and display them on a drop down menu where the user selects.

So far I have only managed to pass parameters from shiny to SQL:

R sevrer:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$hist <- renderPlot({

table1 <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = 
          paste("
            SELECT sum(sales_amount) as sum, sum(sales_amount) as sum2
    from table s
    join table2 c on c.key = s.key
    join table3 d on d.date = s.date
            WHERE year_number = ",input$segment,"

          "))
plot(table1$sum, table1$sum2)
})

})
```

Shiny:

```
ui <-(fluidPage(
selectInput(inputId = "segment",
      label = "segment",
      choices = c('2016', '2017', '2018'),
      selected = '2018'),

plotOutput("hist")

))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I would now like to do the opposite. 
Instead of having to hardcode the years, I want to get them from an SQL query.

I don't have the slightest idea how to do that.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost done just want to load the table data into your `selectinput` area. like shown below ,

R Server:

```
server <- shinyServer(function(input, output) {

output$hist <- renderPlot({

table1 <- dbGetQuery(con, statement = 
          paste("
            SELECT sum(sales_amount) as sum, sum(sales_amount) as sum2
    from table s
    join table2 c on c.key = s.key
    join table3 d on d.date = s.date
            WHERE year_number = ",input$segment,"

          "))
plot(table1$sum, table1$sum2)
})

})
```

ui :

```
table2 <- dbGetQuery (con1, "select year_number from yourtable")

ui <-(fluidPage(
selectInput("segment", "segment", sort(unique(table2$year_number)),selected = NULL),    
plotOutput("hist")

))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for the tip. I have gotten the logic of what you are doing but I keep getting this error:                                                                          
    Error in table2$year_number : $ operator not defined for this S4 class

Comment: I finally got it working! I sued dbGetQuery instead of sendQuery. I also removed the '%s' and it just worked! Thanks a gazillion!

Comment: I will, Thanks for the swift responses.

Answer (score 0):

You need to calculate year of each sale and then use group by clause to group result set by years. Then into select clause you could use sum() for each year.

Comment: I was thinking of having a separate query that just gives me alist of years like: 'SELECT year from table' then it will give me a list of years.                     The problem is how to get those years on a dropdown menu in shiny